# CloudKit and recordType in iOS. What characters are allowed for record type?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I am working on CloudKit but keep getting character not allowed error.
What characters are allowed?

Answer (score 5):

In the docs for [`CKRecord.init(recordType:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKRecord/initWithRecordType:) it says:

> Record type names must consist of one or more alphanumeric characters
>   and must start with a letter. Type names may include underscore
>   characters as long as they do not start with that character. Spaces
>   are not allowed in the names.